# Getting profile id from page source

Tags: php, excel, vba, facebook-php-sdk, phpexcel

I want to lookup for facebook profile id of a user. I tried few things in php and excel by doing an extensive google search but was unable to do it.

Eg.
If I go to https://www.facebook.com/zuck, in the source code, I see "profile_id":4. Here 4 is the profile ID for Mark Zuckerberg. Likewise I need to identify profile IDs of few people and I have their facebook urls ready with me. What is the best way to do this? PHP, Excel, Javascript or any other language.

Please help me with a start as i am struggling for this since two days.

Thanks

EDIT:
In excel I was doing something like this

```
Sub find()

Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        ie.Visible = False
        ie.Navigate "http://findfacebookid.com/"
    ie.Visible = True

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.StatusBar = "Downloading information, lease wait..."
        DoEvents
    Loop

    pro = ie.Document.getElementsByID("profile_id")
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: If you are doing it for just one facebook profile id at a time and not looping over a range of facebook profile links then using IE shouldn't be a problem. But your above code doesn't do anything. Where are you entering the Facebook profile URL? And where are you searching for result?

Comment: the above code is not working. the approach was different as i was finding profile id from findfacebookid.com website but later i discovered that the profile id is in the source itself. I have around 125+ urls and want to loop it but just unable to find a way to do it.

Comment: You could use XMLHttp in that case? You can get the source in a string and then parse the relevant data?

Comment: parsing syntax is the issue. I am trying though. however, appreciate if you can help me or give me some reference to look for. Thanks for your replies. Also I need a logic... what will be better to do. Keeping all urls in notepad, database, excel file and how to go about parsing it using xml

Comment: Posted a short example on how to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I do not know `php` nor do I work with `Facebook Apis`. It is quite possible that those methods may offer you something better

---

Here is a sample code which will give you the ID in less than 2 seconds. The below is a code in `Excel-VBA` which I tested on couple of Profile links (*including mine*) and it worked.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim webSource As String
    Dim tmpString As String

    sURL = "https://www.facebook.com/zuck"

    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        webSource = .responsetext
    End With

    tmpString = Split(webSource, "profile_id=")(1)
    tmpString = Split(tmpString, "&amp;")(0)

    Debug.Print tmpString '<~~ Gives 4
End Sub
```

If you have a list of URLs then you can either keep it in a notepad or in an excel range. it doesn't matter. Ensure that you read all that data in an array and then use that for looping.

**Followup from Comments**

> I tried in both ways, if I keep inside the loop it works for only first id and fails on the next ones. If I keep outside the loop, then how can i open sURL from the .Open command? What I did was, For r = 1 To 150 sURL = Range("A" & r).Value and Next r at the end. Can you please edit the code and show me the correct way please? –  Sabha 27 secs ago

I have commented the code but if you still have questions, simply ask :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim webSource As String, tmpString As String
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> This is the worksheet which has ids.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        '~~> Assuming that the urls are in Col A
        '~~> Find last row of col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            For i = 1 To lRow
                sURL = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
                .Open "GET", sURL, False
                .send

                webSource = .responseText

                If InStr(1, webSource, "profile_id=") Then
                    tmpString = Split(webSource, "profile_id=")(1)
                    tmpString = Split(tmpString, ",")(0)
                ElseIf InStr(1, webSource, "profile_id"":") Then
                    tmpString = Split(webSource, "profile_id"":")(1)
                    tmpString = Split(tmpString, ",")(0)
                End If
                '~~> The ids will be written to Col B
                If tmpString <> "" Then ws.Range("B" & i).Value = tmpString
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have understood the concept. Will try the solution and reply. Just a question. If I keep it in a range (for eg. in column A from A1:A150), I will definitely need to have a For Loop. Is it better to keep the createobject within the loop? or just the tmpString split in the loop? Thanks

Comment: `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` will be outside the loop

Comment: I tried in both ways, if I keep inside the loop it works for only first id and fails on the next ones. If I keep outside the loop, then how can i open sURL from the .Open command? What I did was, For r = 1 To 150 sURL = Range("A" & r).Value and Next r at the end. Can you please edit the code and show me the correct way please?

Comment: Updated the post.. you may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: Oh yes! I just saw that. I tried it but again same issue. It works only for the first id and then error. Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range on the line tmpString = Split(webSource, "profile_id=")(1)

Comment: Also if you can share the url which doesn't work for you?

Comment: Also try the updated code. this will skip the faulty urls and not give you an error.

Comment: I was giving you those IDs that do not work but before sending, I chose to refresh assuming that I may miss your reply. I tried your revised code and it seems to be working. Let me try this for all my 150 IDs. I will come back to you. Thanks

Comment: If you come across an url which doesn't work then i need to see it to give you a more concrete solution :)

Comment: Thank you so much. The output produced is accurate on the sample testing that I did. I will definitely reply if I come across any faulty url. You rightly said that PHP, FB API/SDK may give even better results because the excel code runs a little slow. Nevertheless, all is well that ends well. Thank you so much for your kind cooperation.

Comment: Hey brother... I liked your code and was studying it. One thing I did not understand, why is there a "ElseIf InStr"? It is exactly the same as "If InStr". And why is the Dim MyAr for? Eagerly awaiting your reply

Comment: `ElseIf` will check for then 2nd condition. The `Dim MyAr` is a leftover which I forgot to remove. You can ignore that

Comment: Yes, thats right! but 1st and 2nd conditions both are same and since they are same, it will never go to second condition. If my thoughts are incorrect, please give me a scenario when the code will go to second condition. I also wanted to ask you if there are multiple profile_ids in the websource, how can i capture all? Thanks

Comment: Sorry. Seems like I copied the same thing over. I have rectified that. What you you mean by multiple profile id's. Each id will have single ID

Comment: great... now it makes sense. That colon (:) was the culprit :) By multiple profile id, i meant getting different IDs. Eg. I have another url that has more than one profile IDs mentioned one after the other. I tried modifying your code to loop through the websource to find these multiple IDs but everytime I get the first ID. Your code searches for profile_id and splits the uid and store it in tmpstring. I want it to go further looking for a different profile_id and split its uid and so on... until it finishes all profile_ids in the websource. I hope you understood what I meant. Thanks

Comment: can you share one such link?

Comment: Sure... https://www.facebook.com/browse/group_members/?gid=828910120462968&edge=groups%3Amembers this is the link and i modified your code to get both (full profile url) and (profile id) by adding one more tempstring2 but everytime i got the first record and i didnt know where to stop the loop because it was difficult for me to find total profiles in that url.